# How to test nginx subdomains on localhost

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I want to test nginx subdomains before uploading config to the server. Can i test it on localhost? I try

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  sub.localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/sub;
    }
}
```

And it does not work. Shoulld i change my hosts file in order to make it work? Also, after uploading site to the server should i change DNS records and add sub.mydomain.com?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, add '127.0.0.1 sub.localhost' to your hosts file. That sub has to be resolved somehow. That should work.

Then once you're ready to go to the net, yes, add an a or cname record for the subdomain sub.

When I use proxy_pass I also include the proxy.conf from nginx.
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule

Comment: The line in `/etc/hosts` should read `127.0.0.1 localhost sub.localhost`

Answer (score 10):

In Linux based OS just to edit as `sudo` `/etc/hosts` file and change `127.0.0.1 localhost` to `127.0.0.1 *.localhost`.

So at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<environment>/<your_project_name>` edit `server_name` key as `<subdomain>.localhost`.

Reload nginx and networking service.

```
$ sudo service nginx reload
$ sudo service networking reload
```

And then try `http://<subdomain>.localhost` at url bar.

It works for me.

**UPDATE**

In my opinion, a better solution is creating a virtual server that only responds if subdomain doesn’t exist, at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/development/default`, as default server (remember that you can define only one server as default).

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  root /var/www/html/errors/404;
  server_name *.localhost *.<host-name>;

  location / {
    index subdomain.html;
  }

}
```

Make sure that in `nginx.conf` (generally at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`) contain `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/**/*;` to this virtual server work. If not, put it and then run `$ sudo service nginx reload`.

In this case isn't necessary put `*.localhost` in `/etc/hosts`, but only `localhost`.

Comment: Wildcards like `*` are not allowed in `/etc/hosts` according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html

Comment: wildcards are allowed only with `localhost` but not with any other domain names.

Answer (score 8):

For your public webserver with its own domain name, you just need to add a Canonical name using a CNAME record in your DNS configuration:

```
CNAME    *    example.com.
```

Once this is done, set your nginx setting

```
server_name  *.example.com example.com;
```

In your local setup you can keep the same configuration for nginx but unless you have a local DNS setup, you will have to edit your /etc/hosts file and add each subdomain manually. wildcards don't work in the /etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1  abc.example.com def.example.com ghi.example.com
```

It is generally recommended to use .local as the namespace for your local domains.

Answer (score 1):

With an Nginx configuration like shown by the OP, all that is needed is to configure the local DNS resolution. I run Linux containers on a VM with a local DHCP IP but test them on Windows 10 browsers.

The DNS configuration can be done by editing *"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"* as Administrator.

```
192.168.100.50  sub.example.local
192.168.100.50  example.local
```

Of course, use `127.0.0.1` or other appropriate IP as needed.