# Add subdomain to localhost URL

Tags: http, url

I am writing an web application that behaves differently depending on a url prefix. The format is something like:

```
   https://myprefix.mycompany.com
```

The web app behaves differently based on myprefix. My web app extract that part from the URL and act on that.

However, when I test on my local, I use an localhost address:

```
   https://localhost:1234
```

I counldn't do something like:

```
   https://myprefix.localhost:1234
```

What is the best way for me to test this scenario?

Many thanks

Comment: Here is the solution of this issue

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/29629675/2950006

Comment: I think, you should use nginx. similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095219/how-to-test-nginx-subdomains-on-localhost

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Unfortunately, because `localhost` is not a proper domain, you can't add a subdomain to it like that. You *can*, however, trick your computer into thinking it owns a specific domain and test things that way. For instance, if you have a UNIX-based operating system, open (as root) the file `/etc/hosts` and add a line (or lines) like this:

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
127.0.0.1    subdomain.example.com
```

Your computer will now treat both `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com` as belonging to itself. If you visit either in your web browser, they will work the same, in principle, as `localhost`, but your web server will see the correct domain in its Host header.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I want. However, my web app runs on a port, say 1234. I searched around and people said there is no way to specify a port number in /etc/hosts. What is the best way to specify port?

Comment: You're going to have to just use the port in your URL as usual, e.g., `http://subdomain.example.com:1234/whatever`. The port is entirely separate from the domain (domains are used for identifying the machine, ports are used for identifying which program on the machine to communicate with).

Comment: Alternatively, if you can run your software as root (for testing), you can just use port 80, which is the default, so you won't have to specify one.

Comment: One could just list the domain names after the ip address:   `127.0.0.1 example.com sub.example.com sub2.example.com...`

Comment: This works for windows as well.  The host file on windows is located at: `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.  You will need to copy the file to somewhere else that has lower permissions, (like your desktop), to edit it and then paste it back into the folder (to work around the permissions).

Comment: @Shimmy I added the line `127.0.0.1   m.test.mydomain.com` to the hosts file, I was then able to hit `http://m.test.mydomain.com:8000` (which went to my local server).  Did you maybe copy the example in the file and leave the comment character (`#`) in?

Comment: @sel-en-ium I got it to work now. My issue was with the IIS configurations. Thank you!

Comment: I did this and it gave me this error `Invalid Host header`

Comment: Surprisingly, on Windows 11 I can type http://w.localhost:3010 into browser, and it will open website on that port, as if it was localhost. In javascript, window.location.host is set as expected.

Answer (score 61):

I'm not sure about same behaviour on windows. I'm working on linux mint.

You can use `lvh.me:port` as a local domain. You can imagine that your project is deployed on `localhost:port` on this domain.

Instead of `sub.localhost:port` you've to use `sub.lvh.me:port`

**UPDATE**

`sub.localhost:port` works on Chrome.

Note: Firefox automatically adds www. at the beginning of entered domain that can cause problems with subdomains testing

Comment: I can confirm this works on Windows as well. Internet Explorer, Edge, Firefox, and Chrome browsers work flawlessly!

Comment: I was using firefox and chrome tip saved my day, thanks!

Comment: For additional flexibility, you could also use the services nio.io or xip.io. They allow to map any IP address to any subdomain. So e.g. your colleagues could also use the same URL to access your app.

E.g. if your workstation's IP address is `172.16.0.42`, you could use `https://myprefix.myapp.172.16.0.42.nip.io:1234` from your PC or from other PCs in your intranet.

Answer (score 11):

For Windows users, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016600/75500) answer and per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016553/add-subdomain-to-localhost-url#comment97723808_19016600) comment, you can achieve this by adding ports to localhost via the *hosts* file that resides at this path:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

And append lines like the following to it:

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
127.0.0.1    subdomain.example.com
```

Answer (score 5):

### One-Line Solution for Windows

Open **PowerShell** as **Administrator** and run the following command, replacing `sub.mydomain.com` with whatever you want.

```
"`n127.0.0.1    sub.mydomain.com" | Out-File C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts -encoding ASCII -append
```

#### Breakdown:

- `` `n `` - newline
- `127.0.0.1` - loopback address
- `sub.mydomain.com` - domain name
- `| Out-File C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` - pipe the string to the `hosts`
- `-encoding ASCII` - correct encoding
- `-append` - append to end of file **(important!)**

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the `.test` domain for things like that.  That is what `.test` is for.  `localhost` is not supposed to have any subdomains.

To do so violates the approved RFC standards.  `localhost` has an A record and in IPv6 environments, an AAAA record.  All other DNS record types, including SOA are forbidden.

Without an SOA record, it cannot be a zone apex that has sub-records, so no subdomains nor delegations are permitted.  Even the recent RFC draft titled Let localhost be localhost is consistent with this.

Comment: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN this comes after

Comment: Actually, RFC standards [referenced by IANA](https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved) explicitly [allow subdomains for `localhost`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761.html#section-6.3): 'The domain "localhost." **and any names falling within ".localhost."** are special...'

Is there another RFC standard that contradicts this?

Answer (score 4):

It took me a bit of time to find public wildcard DNS domains pointing to localhost so I'm leaving it here for future reference.

The domain that worked for me is `localtest.me`. That domain and its sub-domains resolve to `127.0.0.1` and `::1`.
For example:

```bash
$ host localtest.me
localtest.me has address 127.0.0.1
localtest.me has IPv6 address ::1
```

```bash
$ host some-sub-domain.localtest.me
some-sub-domain.localtest.me has address 127.0.0.1
some-sub-domain.localtest.me has IPv6 address ::1
```

A maintained list of other public wildcard DNS domains that point to localhost can be found in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/tinogomes/c425aa2a56d289f16a1f4fcb8a65ea65).

Comment: Note that DNS rebinding protection needs to be turned *off* in the DNS server used to serve any such requests.

Answer (score 2):

```
https://myprefix.mycompany.localhost:1234
```

This should do the trick. Because `localhost` is a top-level-domain, it behaves like a `.com` in production code.

Comment: This seems non-standard and might lack support :) Windows + NODE-Fetch(v2.6.4) does not map subdomain.localhost to 127.0.0.1 - afaik Linux did not have an issues. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63515360/3114702

Comment: I have tried this and works (xampp on W11, localhost and subdomain.locahost work).

Answer (score 2):

**From WSL in Windows**:

- First navigate to `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/drivers/etc`(Navigate cause, you may find more interesting files. Don't play here, but see what do they do)
- Then do `nano hosts`(add at very bottom)

  ```
  127.0.0.1    random.com
  127.0.0.1    auth.random.com
  ```