# Apache vhost not working for subdomains

Tags: apache, vhosts

I have this configuration but both url app.test.com & stage.test.com 
redirect to same code/deployment

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Test-Prod/web
    <Directory "/var/www/html/Test-Prod/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog logs/test-prod__error_log
    CustomLog logs/test-prod_access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName stage.test.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Test/web
   <Directory "/var/www/html/Test/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog logs/test-website_error_log
   CustomLog logs/test-website_access_log common
 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual error for this is leaving out the `NameVirtualHost` directive if you're still using httpd 2.2

Add the following in your config file and it'll probably work

```
NameVirtualHost *.80
```

You might want to read the documentation for [Named-based Virtual Host Support with httpd 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).

Comment: It works. I just uncommented the NameVirtualHost *:80
entry in  httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

```
NameVirtualHost *.80

<VirtualHost localhost:80>
    ServerName color
    ServerAlias localhost
    ServerPath "C:/wamp/www/subwww/color"
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/subwww/color">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

in above code, subdomain name is color

and the url is http://color.localhost/

if the operating system is windows then add "127.0.0.1 color.localhost" in "C:/windows/system32/dirvers/etc/hosts" with notepad run as administration