# Subdomain on localhost ASP.NET webform project

Tags: c#, asp.net

My team is creating a project that allows different users to use the web application based on different sub-domain. That is to say. http://P1.example.com will has its own set of P1's user and http://P2.example.com will has its own set of P2's user.

We do not have the structural issues with the database and the code but we have questions regarding the project's setup. I have read similar questions and answers here but they are not leading me to the right direction:
[Add subdomain to localhost URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016553/add-subdomain-to-localhost-url) and 
[Apache vhost not working for subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446387/apache-vhost-not-working-for-subdomains/29629675#29629675) as they are not windows-based.

Question:

1. How do I setup such that I can test subdomains on visual studio on localhost settings. What are the setup we need to do?
2. What should I do to trick the computer and tell it to "redirect" the requests all P1.localhost to localhost and P2.localhost to localhost but maintaining the URL in the browser?

Comment: Just set up the relevant sites in iis and add entries to your hosts file like `p1.example.com 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a normal site in IIS and assign it a binding of subdomain.localhost

Then in your hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) add an entry

```
127.0.0.1     subdomain.localhost
```

Sorry for this being quite short, I assume that you already know how to set up a site in IIS.