# service worker on subdomain on localhost

Tags: service-worker

My application is based on subdomains and I am trying to use service workers in my application.

1. How do I run service worker on abc.localhost.com . I understand google has not whitelisted subdomains on localhost to use service workers but is there a work around?
2. I cannot get service worker to work in development mode.

There is app folder that has the application content.

If I register service-worker in app folder, I cannot cache bower components and then app does not work offline.

If I register service worker outside of app folder, index.html which is in app folder, is never able to find path of servie-worker.js which is outside of app folder, in the root directory.

I have tried this in index.html:

```
if( 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register( '../service-worker.js' , { scope : ' ' } )
      .then( function( ) {
        console.log('Congratulations!!Service Worker Registered');
      })
      .catch( function( err) {
        console.log(`Aagh! Some kind of Error :- ${err}`);
      });
  } else {
    console.log("SW NOT SUPPORTED");
    //still not supported
  }
```

But I only get 404.

I have also tried using absolute path i.e

```
  .register( '/service-worker.js' , { scope : ' ' } )
```

Comment: I think this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016600/1566735

Comment: Also, why are you registering the service worker with an empty scope value ?

Answer (score 0):

Since service worker only work for `localhost` and `https/ssl` url

My flow for service worker + subdomain on local machine is create `https` url for my development env, i use https://myapp.local and https://subdomain.myapp.local point to 127.0.0.1:

1. Install webserver on your local machine (Nginx/Apache/etc)
2. Setup your local app with that webserver
3. edit `/etc/hosts` file for local domain host config (myapp.local, subdomain.myapp.local)
4. Setup OpenSSL for that webserver (now we able to use `https`)
5. trust your open certificates (example ref for mac https://tosbourn.com/getting-os-x-to-trust-self-signed-ssl-certificates, not tested, just googling, forgot my real reference) so you able access with green ssl on your browser.
6. take a coffee.