# wildcard sub-domain on localhost using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, localhost, subdomain, wildcard

I have setup virtual host on my localhost by using codeigniter and it is working fine. But I am not able to create wildcard subdomains. To add virtual host below are my steps on windows machine.

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt
```

In this host.txt I have added below line

```
127.0.0.1           localhost.com
```

I am using xampp .I have added below lines in  httpd-vhosts.conf file.
D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost localhost.com:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/adeptra"
    ServerName localhost.com
    ServerAlias localhost.com

    <Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/adeptra">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/adeptra"
    ServerName localhost.com
    ServerAlias *.localhost.com
<Directory "D:/xampp/htdocs/adeptra">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Below is my .htaccess code to remove index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

So now my question is, is it really possible to create wildcard subdomains in localhost? If yes, then please help me in this regard. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has already been asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19016600/6556047). Basically, no you cannot create subdomains on localhost. You need to create a local domain which is explained in the linked answer.