# multiple vhosts working on Chrome, but not Firefox or Safari

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vhosts

I’m using [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and [vhost](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vhost) to set up multiple servers on the same port, each with a different subdomain. Each server corresponds to a local directory on my file system. They only need to serve static files.

### ~/repos/server/app.js:

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const express = require('express')
const vhost   = require('vhost')

const app = express()
const PORT = 9000
const virtual_hosts = require('./virtual-hosts.json') // see below

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../')))

virtual_hosts.forEach((vh) => {
    var vh_app = express()
    vh_app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../', vh.path)))
    app.use(vhost(vh.domain, vh_app))
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`
        Listening at http://localhost:${PORT}/
        Press ctrl + c to stop.
    `)
    console.log('...')
})
```

### ~/repos/server/virtual-hosts.json:

```
[
    { "domain": "repo1.localhost", "path": "./repo1/" },
    { "domain": "repo2.localhost", "path": "./repo2/" },
    { "domain": "repo3.localhost", "path": "./repo3/" }
]
```

After running `node ~/repos/server/app.js`, the url `http://localhost:9000/repo1/index.html` works in all 3 browsers, but `http://repo1.localhost:9000/index.html` only works in Chrome, but not Firefox or Safari.

Is there something wrong with my code, or do I need to change some browser settings?

Comment: update: I found this, but not sure if it will help: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1011327

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit late, but for someone who come up with the same question.

You can't use subdomains **on windows** of "localhost". I dont know how chrome manage to handle it, but the normal behaviour is that you can't do that.

If you still want to archieve this, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016553/add-subdomain-to-localhost-url).