# Cookie based authentication on multiple 'localhost' Asp.Net Core Sites

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Scenario is only an issue on a development machine.

I have multiple different and entirely independent ASP.NET Core 2.2 projects running on my dev machine under "localhost".

Once I successfully authenticate and log in on one project, I can no longer log in to the other projects.  I'm assuming it's something to do with the auth cookies.

All projects have the same identical and basic Identity authentication.

```
    services.AddAuthentication();

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>
    {
        opt.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.None;
        opt.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;                
        opt.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
        opt.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
    });
```

The sign-in call is succeeding:

`result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(portal.ID, model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true, loggedInUser);`

However, once the user is redirected to the home page, which required authentication, I see the following in the debug output:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed.`

... and the user is kicked back to the login page.

Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opt =>
{
    opt.Cookie.Name = "Unique Value Per App";
});
```

All I have to do is post on SO and the problem solves itself!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider running your sites under different domains, and then mapping the domains to localhost (or rather, 127.0.0.1) in your hosts file.

This question explains the technique: [Add subdomain to localhost URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016553/add-subdomain-to-localhost-url)

Here is an article which explains the hosts file for different operating systems: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: Clever!  Thank you.