# Laravel route exist but unable to view page

Tags: php, laravel

I have been invited to collaborate on a laravel 7 project and I have been able to set up the project locally on a windows 10 system using wamp server. While reviewing the project, I noticed the plan is to use subdomain routing. I am currently tasked with setting up the blade templates and I want to test the route but I can't get the route to work correctly even though the routes exist. This is what the routes look like
[image]

When i try viewing the page for realestate by calling the url like this `realestate.localhost:8000` I get the connection error below
[image]

The route is inside `routes/realestate.php` folder and its using a closure

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Realestate Routes';
});
```

What is the right way to call the route in my local enviroment on windows?

Comment: that is not Laravel, you have miss-configured  the server, the domain is not pointing to the laravel project

Comment: how would your computer know what host these domains (subdomains) are pointing to?

Comment: @Berto99 this is in my development environment and not on a live serve. I am able to get to the welcome page using `http://localhost:8000` but have issues when trying to get `http://realestate.localhost:8000`

Comment: @lagbox I have no idea hence my reason for posting the question.

Comment: understood, i was thinking of something like a 'hosts' file perhaps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your environment is different from mine, but make sure you're accessing via `http://` and not `https://`

I just saw your Route code - it's been a long day, sorry :P
Try reading up on Subdomain routing [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing).

Your Route should look like this:

```
Route::domain('realestate.localhost')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return 'Hello, world!'
    });
    
    // all other routes for realestate.localhost go in here
});
```

Comment: I am accessing through http like so `http://realestate.localhost:8000` but not successful. However I am able to get to the home page using `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Just updated my answer for you! Sorry I didn't see your route code before. :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your hosts and add redirect to localhost from your subdomain. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921347/11775360