# is it possible in flutter web to add prefix to the domain?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am new in flutter web development and I need little help from you people. I am building an app in flutter web and  in the domain of that app I want to add the prefix
for example:

> (**shop.)localhost.com**

or

> **(user123341.)localhost.com.**

If you people have any small information about this please share your information. It will really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is completely possible to upload a Flutter Web App to a subdomain as Flutter compiles to Javascript and HTML. You can upload it to any subdomain you wish. But in your case you want to do that using `localhost`.

You need to understand that localhost is not purely a domain and you can't add a subdomain to it. But there are some workarounds to do that:

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921347/6915572), you can try adding subdomains to the localhost as illustrated below.

```
 C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

And append lines like the following to it:

```
127.0.0.1    example.com
127.0.0.1    subdomain.example.com
```